# logic of color variance

Tags: php, colors, gd

http://dribbble.com/colors/1a15a1?percent=5&variance=50

I understand the color minimum slider--you would count the color of each pixel, then create a ratio for a particular color based on the total pixels of the image (10 blue:100 total) = 10% blue.

But what's the logic behind the color variance slider? Looking at the RGB values of these colors http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_colors#X11_color_names some patterns are apparent, but imagining a sql table full of pictures and their pixel data, anyone have an idea on how to calculate variance?

Answer (score 2):

I too think you are right for the color minimum. Color variance is easy too. If you select a small variance you will get images with a small count of colors used on it. Logically 0% variance must bring an image of a single color only.

I don't think you have to store pixels at all, logically for storing a new image it goes like this:

1. Read image file
2. Find how many different color there are in it
3. Store image path and number of different colors on it.

Then on retriving the image would go like this:

1. Ask the user what variance he likes
2. Let's say variance = 60%
3. Read distinct maximum numbers of colors for an image
4. MaxColors = 100% (let's say max=18 colors per image)
5. Turn 60% to integer
   18 = 100%
   x = 60% then
   18*60=100*x then 100*x=1080 then x=10.8
6. Make 10.8 round so it becomes x=11
7. Retrieve from database all images that have 11 or more colors on them
8. Display these images as the result

So no need to store any pixel at all, just a single integer that indicates how many colors consist of an image.

Comment: I don't know if it's the correct answer for the question, but it's a great logic. +1 for this.